# Subsonic\ORM on Windows CE\Mobile

Tags: orm, windows-mobile, subsonic

Has anyone managed to get subsonic or a variant working on Windows Mobile? We cant get it to work as it has a dependency on System.Configuration.

Any suggestions on an alternate ORMs that would work on a windows mobile device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague of mine used [EntitySpaces](http://www.entityspaces.net) on a Windows Mobile project and was pretty pleased with it.

Comment: But you have to pay for it? :(

Answer (score 1):

Is the System.Configuration dependency the only issue?  If so, you could always try to get around it by adding that capability.  For example [OpenNETCF's SDF](http://opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx) has an OpenNETCF.Configuration namespace that mirrors a lot of the System.Configuration namespace.  You might be able to eitehr modify subsonic to use that namespace, or modify and recompile the SDF's assembly to use System.Configuration as a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at something like [LLBLGEN](http://www.llblgen.com/pages/features.aspx) which shows support for the compact framework.